How to mitigate some emojis consuming the whitespace character following them?
I have a list of strings, like this:
data = [
"-  T-SHIRT",
"- ⛱️ UMBRELLA",
"-  CAR",
"- ️ COMPUTER"
]

In Python, when I loop over data, most lines print() fine, however some emojis eat the single whitespace character that succeeds and divides them from their individual labels (i.e. text), and the terminal output turns out like this:
for line in data:
    print(line)

Terminal output:
 -  T-SHIRT
 - ⛱️UMBRELLA
 -  CAR
 - ️COMPUTER

In reality, I read the emojis and labels from a text file and don't know which emoji poses this problem and which outputs fine.
What is this behavior due to and how can I mitigate it?

Update (May 23, 2024):
With great insights that @Andj and @t.niese provided so far, I managed to understand that:

it's most probably an issue with how the terminal emulator interprets and outputs the grapheme cluster (i.e. emoji), especially ones that include the variation selector-16
I can append a whitespace character to the grapheme cluster to remedy the issue above, if and only if I can faithfully identify problematic ones

This is the update data set that I'm currently testing:
DATA = [, ⛱, , , , ]

The shirt and car emojis are fine. The rest pose issues.
I can identify the umbrella and the computer emoji with a modified, stripped down version of @Andj's code from below:
import unicodedata

DATA = [
    "",
    "⛱️ ",
    "",
    "️ ",
    " ",
    " "
]

def codepoints(text):
    return [(c, f"{ord(c):04X}", unicodedata.name(c)) for c in text]

for d in DATA:
    cp = codepoints(d) + [len(d)]
    print(cp)

This outputs:
[('', '1F455', 'T-SHIRT'), 1]
[('⛱', '26F1', 'UMBRELLA ON GROUND'), ('️', 'FE0F', 'VARIATION SELECTOR-16'), 2]
[('', '1F697', 'AUTOMOBILE'), 1]
[('', '1F5A5', 'DESKTOP COMPUTER'), ('️', 'FE0F', 'VARIATION SELECTOR-16'), 2]
[('', '1F58B', 'LOWER LEFT FOUNTAIN PEN'), 1]
[('', '1F6E0', 'HAMMER AND WRENCH'), 1]

The umbrella and computer can be identified by the VARIATION SELECTOR-16.
However, the fountain pen and hammer and wrench pass as single character emojis without VARIATION SELECTOR-16, but still cause the whitespace character in front to disappear.
Does anybody know how to nail down cases like these to?

What Ide are you using? It is coming perfect on my Jupyter notebook.

This an issue that is known for emoji in terminals. E.g. for emojify there was a pull request  targeting such an issue.

@TalhaTayyab, VIM

@St4rb0y I assume the terminals are having trouble with U+FE0F (VARIATION SELECTOR-16). The two of the four examples that show spacing defect.s are also the two of the examples that contain variation selectors, i.e they are two codepoints long.

@Andj, interesting! Is there a way to maybe detect this in Python, to see the emoji's underlying code and whether this variation selector is present?

@St4rb0y I use some personal code, easiest is to just covert a emoji to a list of characters, then loop through them printing the character, the codepoint, character name, category and other details you might want. I tend to use unicodedataplus rather than the inbuilt unicodedata so I can update and be using latest unicode version, since depending on what version of python you are using, you might be using an older version of unicode and not have access to the data. I have some inhouse code on github I use, but its not ready for release yet, but i can point you to it if you want.

@Andj, can you please tell me how I can convert an emoji to a list of characters?

@St4rb0y, I have added an answer that gives a more detailed info about each character.There are three functions. The first gives a list of codepoints in string. The second gives a list of graphemes in the string, the third prints a table with some property values for each character. Although if you just want an emoji as a list of characters, just use a list comprehension: [char for char in '️'].

The space does not disappear, but is placed in the column occupied by the grapheme of the previous character, since the terminal cannot recognize the latter as requiring 2 columns to display. You may want to read the answers to the question How to know the preferred display width in columns of Unicode characters as well as the comment on the wcwidth function

@St4rb0y an answer needs to know what terminal/console application you are using, what operating system, and what emoji font is being used on your system. Results for different combinations will differ, so it is necessary to tailor the results. on macOS I get different results in different terminal/console apps, and emoji play havoc with terminal multiplexers as well. But a hack for one terminal tends to make another terminal worse.

@St4rb0y If you look at the COMPUTER emoji (1F5A5) with VS16 if should be displayed as an emoji, with VS15 it should be displayed as text mode. The default without variation selector should be text mode. in emoji mode it should require 2 terminal cells, in text mode it should require 1 terminal cell. Unfortunately most terminals I've tested always display the character in emoji mode rather regardless of teh presence of a VS or not, or which VS. I've updated my answer to try to get it to work on at least one of my terminals'

@Andj, iTerm2 on macOS

@St4rb0y, which version of iTerm2, and which version of macOS? Your tests work fine for me without any adjustments in iTerm2. Wondering if its a change in iTerm2 or different fonts being used.

@St4rb0y have you tested with profiles?

@Andj, I've just installed the Nord theme in iTerm 2. I'm using the latest version as well as the latest release of Sonoma.

@St4rb0y, I'm on an older version of iTerm and macOS, I'll try to update iTerm and see if that changes anything.

@St4rb0y, if i exclude  LOWER LEFT FOUNTAIN PEN and HAMMER AND WRENCH, all the emoji and spacing displays correctly using iterm2 3.5.1beta4 on macOS Monterey. The version of teh Apple Color Emoji font on Monterey doesn't support LOWER LEFT FOUNTAIN PEN and HAMMER AND WRENCH so i can't test those. But all the other emoji have no spacing problems. If you edit your current iTerm profile, on the text tab, there is an option to use Unicode version 9+ widths, is this ticked or unticked? .

@Andj, It's ticked. "Ambiguous characters are double-width" is un-ticked and "Unicode normalization form" is set to "None".

Display depends on both the fonts being used, and how the terminal or console handles wide, ambiguous, and zero-width characters. In theory an emoji, whether a single Unicode character, or an extended grapheme cluster representing an emoji, should have a width of two terminal cells in the console. But the console/terminal itself, and the version of Unicode supported, compared to the age of the character all influence actual rendering in the console. On macOS, the default terminal app and iTerm2 will render differently.
To see what your emoji string is composed of:
import unicodedataplus
import regex
import prettytable
from wcwidth import wcwidth

def codepoints(text, prefix = False, extended = False):
    if extended:
        if prefix:
            return [(c, f"U+{ord(c):04X}", unicodedataplus.name(c)) for c in text]
        else:
            return [(c, f"{ord(c):04X}", unicodedataplus.name(c)) for c in text]
    return ' '.join(f"U+{ord(c):04X}" for c in text) if prefix else ' '.join(f"{ord(c):04X}" for c in text)

def graphemes(text):
    return regex.findall(r'\X', text)

def udata(text, ce=False):
    print(f"\nString: {text}")
    print(f"Graphemes: {graphemes(text)}")
    t = prettytable.PrettyTable(["char", "cp", "name", "script", "block", "cat", "bidi", "cc", "wcwidth"])
    for c in list(text):
        if unicodedataplus.name(c,'-')!='-':
            t.add_row([c, "%04X"%(ord(c)),
                unicodedataplus.name(c,'-'),
                unicodedataplus.script(c),
                unicodedataplus.block(c),
                unicodedataplus.category(c),
                unicodedataplus.bidirectional(c),
                unicodedataplus.combining(c),
                wcwidth(c)])
    print(t)
    return None

udata('⛱️️')
udata('‍‍‍')

# or, more succinct:

for char in codepoints('⛱️️', extended = True):
    print(char[0], char[1], char[2], sep="\t")

I've used the regex module (not re) to get grapheme clusters, and unicodedataplus to get certain UCD values for the characters. I use unicodedataplus instead of the inbuild unicodedata since unicodedataplus is updated wih every Unicode version, and I can have access to up to date character data. On the other hand, to update unicodedata, you need to move to a more recent version of Python.
Normally I would use PyICU for Unicode related tasks, but not all users would have icu4c available, so I've rewritten the above code to remove that dependency.
Update:
Many terminals will default to using a codepoint identified as an emoji, but some like COMPUTER should default to text display rather than emoji display. But some consoles will ignore this and display as emoji, even if VS15 is used to force text display. I suspect it may be a font fallback or lack of fallback/rendering issue. Fonts should change.
On macOS for the default terminal app, I leave the VS16 in the data and target a solution on emoji using VS16, other emoji display ok. I'll add a few complex emoji to the mix:
data = [
"-  T-SHIRT",
"- ⛱️ UMBRELLA",
"-  CAR",
"- ️ COMPUTER",
"- ‍ WOMAN LIGHT SKIN TONE",
"- ‍‍ FAMILY WOMAN GIRL BOY"
]

import regex
for line in data:
    if bool(regex.search(r'\uFE0F', line)):
        graphemes = regex.findall(r'\X', line)
        line = "".join([f'{gr} ' if bool(regex.search(r'\uFE0F', gr)) else gr for gr in graphemes])
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line)

In the macOS terminal app, the code above corrects the visual spacing issues:

On iTerm2 app, initial display is fine, using the adjusted code miss aligns the display:

Either choose the terminal/console to your needs, or adjust display on your preferred terminal/console. I can't see a way of making it cross platform or cross app workable. Its also possible some terminals may have problems with the more complex emoji.
But if you add increasingly complex emoji, things will break down, ie, undesired, increased spacing. Using
data = [
"-  T-SHIRT",
"- ⛱️ UMBRELLA",
"-  CAR",
"- ️ COMPUTER",
"- ‍ WOMAN LIGHT SKIN TONE",
"- ‍‍ FAMILY WOMAN GIRL BOY",
"- ❤️‍ HEART ON FIRE",
"- ️‍️ EYE IN SPEECH BUBBLE",
"- ‍️ FACE IN CLOUDS",
"- ‍ HANDSHAKE: MEDIUM SKIN TONE, MEDIUM-DARK SKIN TONE"
]

We get:


thanks for the update. Your initial proposition already worked for my first set of posted emojis, however fails for the pen and crossed hammer and wrench of my extended set posted in my edit above, as does your new suggestion from your edit.

@St4rb0y the hammer and wrench emoji is one of those specified Emoji Presentation Sequences (https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html) it has specific text and emoji representations, so takes both VS15 and VS16.Its behavior is text if VS15, emoji if VS16, if no VS it will be emoji if specifically displayed with emoji. In plain text environments it will depend, could be displayed either way. See https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-style.html

So Hammer and wrench is potentially ambiguous unless VS is explicitly used.

LOWER LEFT FOUNTAIN PEN is also potentially ambiguous as well. So not surprising chaos exists in a console.

tested the two emoji included VS16 with them, and they work with my code. Without VS16, misaligned.

The issue is caused by consoles as it reproduces on Bash too but notably, strings look aligned inside Vim editor.
data=( "-  T-SHIRT" "- ⛱ UMBRELLA" "-  CAR" "-  COMPUTER" )

for s in "${data[@]}";do
    echo "$s"
done

printf "%s\n" "${data[@]}"

Result (space manually removed since SO does not reproduce the issue)
-  T-SHIRT
- ⛱UMBRELLA
-  CAR
- COMPUTER
-  T-SHIRT
- ⛱UMBRELLA
-  CAR
- COMPUTER

For python, using the "ideographic" whitespace or a simple tabulator character does show whitespace
data = [
"-  T-SHIRT",
"- ⛱ UMBRELLA",
"-  CAR",
"-  COMPUTER",
"-  LOWER LEFT PEN",
"-  HAMMER AND WRENCH"

]
for line in data:
    print(line.replace(" ", "\u3000", 2))

data = [
"- \tT-SHIRT",
"- ⛱️\tUMBRELLA",
"- \tCAR",
"- ️\tCOMPUTER"
]
for line in data:
    print(line)

Result looks here better aligned for the first approach but it's the opposite on console
-　　T-SHIRT
-　⛱　UMBRELLA
-　　CAR
-　　COMPUTER
-　　LOWER LEFT PEN
-　　HAMMER AND WRENCH


-     T-SHIRT
- ⛱     UMBRELLA
-     CAR
-      COMPUTER

Another option would be to invert order and right pad the text
- T-SHIRT              
- UMBRELLA             ⛱
- CAR                  
- COMPUTER             
- LOWER LEFT PEN       
- HAMMER AND WRENCH    

With
data = [
("", "T-SHIRT"),
("⛱", "UMBRELLA"),
("", "CAR"),
("", "COMPUTER"),
("", "LOWER LEFT PEN"),
("", "HAMMER AND WRENCH")
]

for d in data:
    print(f"- {d[1]: <20} {d[0]}")

Reverse order and tabulator options screen shot


U+3000 ideographic space should use two terminal cells for display in a terminal. It will ensure there is visible space between all emoji and following text in problematic terminals/consoles. It will not address the underlying issue of spacing and alignment.

@Andj the question does not ask for alignment but for visual spacing between emoji and text. Both options provide such spacing and the tabulator option provides a decent alignment on terminal.

it requires a targeted solution.

@LMC, Thanks for suggestion, it seems to append a space to the problematic emojis, however it also right-pads the okay emojis with another space, which misaligns the emojis and text vertically.

@St4rb0y try the tab options, alignment looks ok on console and keeps the solution simple.
